# Use sql to normalize data in many to many relationships for tableau

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, tableau-api

So I'm trying to make an interactive tableau dashboard. The problem is 2 of my tables have repeating values that don't join together in a nice way (many to many relationship that creates dups)
Here is my raw data in 3 tables:
Employee Info -

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| Last_Name | Salary | Tenure |
+-----------+--------+--------+  
| Hoinski   | 40000  | 2      |  
| Smith     | 90000  | 4      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Employee Status -

```
+-----------+---------+----------+
| Last Name | Status  |   Date   |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| Jones     | On Time | 1/1/2015 |
| Jones     | On Time | 1/2/2015 |
| Jones     | On Time | 1/3/2015 |
| Jones     | On Time | 1/4/2015 |
| Jones     | Missing | 1/5/2015 |
| Hoinski   | On Time | 1/6/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Late    | 1/7/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Late    | 1/8/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Missing | 1/9/2015 |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Employee Risk -

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Last Name |  Risk  |   Date    |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Jones     | High   | 2/10/2014 |
| Jones     | High   | 2/11/2014 |
| Jones     | Low    | 2/12/2014 |
| Jones     | Medium | 2/13/2014 |
| Jones     | Medium | 2/14/2014 |
| Jones     | Medium | 2/15/2014 |
| Jones     | Medium | 2/16/2014 |
| Smith     | Low    | 2/17/2014 |
| Smith     | Medium | 2/18/2014 |
| Smith     | Medium | 2/19/2014 |
| Smith     | Medium | 2/20/2014 |
| Hoinski   | High   | 2/21/2014 |
| Hoinski   | High   | 2/22/2014 |
| Hoinski   | Low    | 2/23/2014 |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

So joining the info table to status is easy, and joining info to risk is easy. But how can I join risk and status? Do I need to join them? What I want to build is 3 charts that interact with each other like this picture:
[image]
The problem is when I click on one pie chart, I can't get the other pie chart to update. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You say you want to join `risk` and `status` but what result would you like? Please provide desire output

Comment: Hi Juan. If I were to click on the "status" pie chart for the "Late" field, it would filter ONLY late records, which ONLY belong to "Hoinski", so the scatter plot would have 1 dot for "Hoinski" and the other pie chart would show Risk for "Hoinski"

Comment: Sorry @barker you probably think is clear for you, but dont have time to try understand what that mean. But if you put some sample data on what your result query should be let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect/hope that your Risk and Status tables each have a row for every date for every employee, and that your Info table has a single row for each employee:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| Last_Name | Salary | Tenure |
+-----------+--------+--------+  
| Hoinski   | 40000  | 2      |  
| Smith     | 90000  | 4      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     |
+-----------+--------+--------+

+-----------+---------+----------+
| Last Name | Status  | Date     |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| Jones     | On Time | 1/1/2015 |
| Hoinski   | On Time | 1/1/2015 |
| Jones     | On Time | 1/2/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Late    | 1/2/2015 |
| Jones     | On Time | 1/3/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Late    | 1/3/2015 |
| Jones     | On Time | 1/4/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Missing | 1/4/2015 |
+-----------+---------+----------+

+-----------+--------+----------+
| Last Name | Risk   | Date     |
+-----------+--------+----------+
| Jones     | High   | 1/1/2015 |
| Smith     | Low    | 1/1/2015 |
| Hoinski   | High   | 1/1/2015 |
| Jones     | High   | 1/2/2015 |
| Smith     | Medium | 1/2/2015 |
| Hoinski   | High   | 1/2/2015 |
| Jones     | Low    | 1/3/2015 |
| Smith     | Medium | 1/3/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Low    | 1/3/2015 |
| Jones     | Medium | 1/4/2015 |
| Smith     | Medium | 1/4/2015 |
| Hoinski   | Low    | 1/4/2015 |
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

According to the picture you provided, it seems like you're interested in showing how many days a given employee was on time (for example), and of those days on which he was on time, how many of those days was his Risk high (for example)? To show that relationship between Risk and Status, we're going to have to include the date in our join. It also looks like you might not have every employee in your Status table, so we'll want to do a left join.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE_RISK
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_STATUS 
ON EMPLOYEE_STATUS.Last_Name = EMPLOYEE_RISK.Last_Name
  AND EMPLOYEE_STATUS.Date = EMPLOYEE_RISK.Date
LEFT_JOIN EMPLOYEE_INFO
  ON EMPLOYEE_RISK.Last_Name = EMPLOYEE_INFO.Last_Name;
```

We'll end up with something like this:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
| Date   | Last Name | Risk   | Status  | Salary | Tenure |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
| 1/1/15 | Jones     | High   | On Time | 120000 | 10     |
| 1/1/15 | Smith     | Low    | NULL    | 90000  | 4      |
| 1/1/15 | Hoinski   | High   | On Time | 40000  | 2      |
| 1/2/15 | Jones     | High   | On Time | 120000 | 10     |
| 1/2/15 | Smith     | Medium | NULL    | 90000  | 4      |
| 1/2/15 | Hoinski   | High   | Late    | 40000  | 2      |
| 1/3/15 | Jones     | Low    | On Time | 120000 | 10     |
| 1/3/15 | Smith     | Medium | NULL    | 90000  | 4      |
| 1/3/15 | Hoinski   | Low    | Late    | 40000  | 2      |
| 1/4/15 | Jones     | Medium | On Time | 120000 | 10     |
| 1/4/15 | Smith     | Medium | NULL    | 90000  | 4      |
| 1/4/15 | Hoinski   | Low    | Missing | 40000  | 2      |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Now we have a record for every day for every employee, with every dimension accounted for. Now that you have a table of raw, unsummarized data, you should be able to just hit **Use as Filter** on each worksheet to get those filters working properly.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew. Not quite so simple, I have no relationship between the status and risk tables besides last name, I can't use the date field. This is why it's giving me problems, I understand the relationship but it's hard to write in sql because you have to aggregate by last name.